# Getting jQuery timeago plugin to recognize newly loaded DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the [jquery timeago plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com) in my Rails 3 application. I have a comments section on my posts#show view that automatically refreshes every 30 seconds with the AJAX used in Railscasts episode #229 ["Polling for Changes"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes). The _comment partial that is loaded by jQuery contains the created_at time of the comment which uses the timeago Rails helper method to create attr tags with the correct time format.

When a comment is submitted and ajax loads the comment, the new comment DOM element isn't recognized by the jQuery timeago plugin. So instead of the time of the comment being displayed as "about a minute ago" it displays "2010-11-21 23:08:36 UTC".

I've googled this problem of course and found suggestions regarding the use of .live(), .delegate() or the livequery plugin.

comments/index.js.erb:

```
<% unless @comments.empty? %>
  $("#comments").append("<%=raw escape_javascript(render(@comments)) %>").timeago();
<% end %>
```

comments/show.js.erb:

```
$("#comments").append("<%=raw escape_javascript(render(@comments)) %>");
```

public/javascripts/application.js:

```
$(function() {
  if ($("#comments").length > 0) {
    setTimeout(updateComments, 30000);
  }
});

function updateComments () {
  var post_id = $("#post").attr("data-id");
  if ($("#comments").length > 0) {
    var after = $(".comment:last-child").attr("data-time");
  } else {
    var after = "0";
  }
  $.getScript("/posts/" + post_id + "/comments?after=" + after)
  setTimeout(updateComments, 30000);
}
```

helpers/application_help.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def timeago(time, options = {})
    options[:class] ||= "timeago"
    content_tag(:abbr, time.to_s, options.merge(:title => time.getutc.iso8601)) if time
  end
end
```

layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.timeago' %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

comments/_comment.html.erb:

```
<div class="comment" data-time="<%= comment.created_at.to_i %>">
  <%- if comment.commenter.empty? -%>
  <%- else -%>   
    <span class="name">
      <%- if comment.email.blank? -%>
        <%= comment.commenter %>:
      <%- else -%>
        <a href="mailto:<%= comment.email %>"><%= comment.commenter %>:</a>
      <%- end -%>
    </span>
  <%- end -%>

  <%= simple_format @comment.body %>

  <span class="time">
    <%= timeago(comment.created_at) %>
  </span>
</div>
```

posts/show.html.erb:

```
<div id="post" data-id="<%= @post.id %>">
  <%= link_to @post.title, @post %>
  <%= simple_format @post.content %>

  <% unless @post.comments.empty? %>
    <div id="comments">
      <%= render @post.comments %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div id="replyform">
  <%= render "comments/form" %>
</div>
```

The AJAX polling and timeago plugin functionality works fine everywhere else, it's just when I make a comment and that comment appears with AJAX from another browser that I run into this issue.
Any suggestions, resources or code would make my week. Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 15):

Your code calls `$("abbr.timeago").timeago();` in a script block in the application template. This runs as the page is loaded for this first time, and enables timeago functionality on matching elements that exist at that moment. Any matching nodes that are added dynamically later on -- for instance your AJAX partial -- do *not* get timeago functionality.

One option is to call `$("abbr.timeago").timeago()` again after adding dynamic content. However, that can be hard to keep track of and remember to do as you add new functionality, which is why I use the [livequery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) instead. Include the livequery script in your page and replace `$("abbr.timeago").timeago();` with the following:

```
$("abbr.timeago").livequery(function () { $(this).timeago(); });
```

This enables timeago on any matching nodes now *and* matching nodes added dynamically.

Comment: It worked fine for me, but the only problem that it has a delay when using with dynamic content, it shows the real time then after a second or 2 it shows the timeago :( which is something bad in many cases to show the ugly date time.

Comment: You can set in you CSS:
.timeago{
    display: none
}

and then in the livequery function just code $(this).show();

Comment: @AmrElgarhy The only way around that is to display a fancy date by default.

Answer (score 4):

Once `load()` has done its thing, `ajaxComplete()` is called. I would advise creating a function called `ready_or_not()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ready_or_not();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
  ready_or_not();
});

function ready_or_not(){
  $(".timeago").timeago();
}
```

There may be certain code that you only want to run when the document is ready, or when Ajax is complete. But for both, put it inside the `ready_or_not()` function.